# UWP Template10 Hide FontIcon element when the menu "IsOpen"

Tags: binding, uwp, winrt-xaml, template10, hamburger-menu

I have the following xaml construct.

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu">
  <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="searchButton">
      <FontIcon x:Name="searchButtonIcon" Width="48"
                                  Height="48"
                                  Glyph="&#xE094;"
                                  Visibility="{Binding IsOpen, ???"/>
      <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find"/>
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="searchButton">
  </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
</Controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

When the menu "IsOpen", the FontIcon element should be collapsed. If the menu not "IsOpen", the FontIcon element should be visible.

The groove music app has such a behaviour (see image in [groove music app with opened menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOcvG.png)).
Which are the parameters for the binding? An explanation for hiding the hamburger button is described in [UWP Template10 Hide hamburger button when menu is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246734/uwp-template10-hide-hamburger-button-when-menu-is-open).

I guess that it's a template10 behaviour. I tried the following within the template10's Shell.xaml page.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBlock x:Name="txt-1" Text="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=MyHamburgerMenu}" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu" Grid.Row="1">
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
      <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt-2" Text="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=MyHamburgerMenu}"/>
      </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
  </Controls:HamburgerMenu>
</Grid>
```

The TextBlock txt-1 displays the correct state of the HamburgerMenu's **IsOpen** property whereas the TextBlock txt-2 is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works.
Change the binding to **x:bind** and reference it to "MyHamburgerMenu".

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu">
  <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="searchButton">
      <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                  Height="48"
                  Symbol="Find"
                  Visibility="{x:Bind MyHamburgerMenu.IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}"/>
      <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find"/>
    </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
  </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
</Controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

and use a invertable BooleanToVisibilityConverter like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IValueConverter to convert the IsOpen to a visibility

```
  public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
      return (!(bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
      return value;
  }


}
```

This article explains IValueConverters and how to use them in your XAML

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter

Comment: The valueconverter is not the problem. I want to know, how to set the FontIcon's visibility property that it depends to the parent Controls:HamburgerMenu.IsOpen state?

Comment: You should be able to Bind to an ElementName for example  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyHamburgerMenu, Path=IsOpen, Converter = {StaticResource MyVisibilityConverter}}"/>

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your effort. I have extended the problem description above.